# PayPal Subscribe (Sandbox): Things don’t appear to be working at the moment

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

Absolutely no settings/code have changed, this all worked 1 week ago (used exact same buyer login to perform test subscription and it worked), now I'm getting following error:

[image: Mystical Paypal error]

I have checked the seller account settings and "block non-encrypted payment URLs" setting is turned OFF. (found some google posts suggesting to check this).

Any help greatly appreciated, as you can see PayPal's error is not very helpful in helping to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now. Since yesterday.

Comment: Issue was with Paypal, is working again now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is (almost certainly) an issue on PayPal's side.

We're seeing the same error on our end, without code changes either.

Unfortunately, the status page doesn't mention this incident at the moment (2022-02-01 15:00:00 UTC):
https://www.paypal-status.com/product/sandbox

Check that page regularly over the next few hours, as well as the "Incident history" page:
https://www.paypal-status.com/history/sandbox

Comment: Thanks Sebastien, I just tried it again now - still not working. Response from merchant technical support: "I checked our logs and could see that the request to PayPal servers failed with 500 Internal error.

I have raised this issue internally with our development team and will provide further update as soon as I hear back from the investigating team. "

Comment: This was an issue on their side. Is now resolved.

Comment: Yes, it's working today for us as well.